# How to name the column when using value_count function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I was counting the no of occurrence of angle and dist by the code below:

```
g = new_df.value_counts(subset=['Current_Angle','Current_dist'] ,sort = False)
```

the output:

```
current_angle    current_dist    0
 -50                30           1
 -50                40           2
 -50                41           6
 -50                45           4
```

try1:
`g.columns = ['angle','Distance','count','Percentage Missed']` - result was no change in the name of column

try2:
When I print the columns using `print(g.columns)` ended with error *`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`*

I want to rename the **column 0** as count and add a new column to the dataframe `g` as **percent missed** which is calculated by 100 - value in column 0

Expected output

```
current_angle    current_dist    count  percent missed
 -50                30           1          99
 -50                40           2          98
 -50                41           6          94
 -50                45           4          96
```

1:How to modify the code? I mean instead of value_counts, is there any other function that can give the expected output?
2. How to get the expected output with the current method?

**EDIT 1**(exceptional case)

data:

| angle | distance | velocity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 124 | -3 |
| 50 | 24 | -25 |
| 50 | 34 | 25 |

expected output:

count is calculated based on distance

| angle | distance | velocity | count | percent missed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 124 | -3 | 1 | 99 |
| 50 | 24 | -25 | 1 | 99 |
| 50 | 34 | 25 | 1 | 99 |

Answer (score 1):

First add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), because [`DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) return `Series`, so possible use parameter `name` for change column `0` to `count` column and then subtract `100` to new column by [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) for subtract from right side like `100 - df['count']`:

```
df = (new_df.value_counts(subset=['Current_Angle','Current_dist'] ,sort = False)
            .reset_index(name='count')
            .assign(**{'percent missed': lambda x: x['count'].rsub(100)}))
```

Or if need also set new columns names use [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df = (new_df.value_counts(subset=['Current_Angle','Current_dist'] ,sort = False)
            .reset_index(name='count')
            .set_axis(['angle','Distance','count'], axis=1)
            .assign(**{'percent missed': lambda x: x['count'].rsub(100)}))
```

If need assign new columns names here is alternative solution:

```
df = (new_df.value_counts(subset=['Current_Angle','Current_dist'] ,sort = False)
            .reset_index())
df.columns = ['angle','Distance','count']
df['percent missed'] = df['count'].rsub(100)
```

Comment: i added an exceptional case in the section **Edit 1 **.When I use value_count i am getting an empty dataframe.Could you please check this?

Comment: @mathew - tested `new_df = pd.DataFrame({'angle': [0, 50, 50], 'distance': [124, 24, 34], 'velocity': [-3, -25, 25]})` with `df = (new_df.value_counts(subset=['angle','distance'] ,sort = False)
            .reset_index(name='count')
            .assign(**{'percent missed': lambda x: x['count'].rsub(100)}))` and working well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a DataFrame as input (if not [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) first), simply use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and a subtraction:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'0': 'count'})   # assuming string '0' here, else use 0
df['percent missed'] = 100 - df['count']
```

output:

```
   current_angle  current_dist  count  percent missed
0            -50            30      1              99
1            -50            40      2              98
2            -50            41      6              94
3            -50            45      4              96
```

###### alternative: using [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
(new_df
 .groupby(['current_angle','current_dist']).size()
 .reset_index(name='count')
 .assign(**{'percent missed': lambda d: 100-d['count']})
)
```

output:

```
   current_angle  current_dist  count  percent missed
0            -50            30      1              99
1            -50            40      2              98
2            -50            41      6              94
3            -50            45      4              96
```